# R compare two columns return third column if any column match conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataset:data1 which have ME and PDR columns.

I want to create this third column: case which would look like this:

```
ME PDR case
1   2   2
NA  1   1
NA  1   1
1   2   2
NA  NA  NA
```

I tried to use this command but it doesn't return me 1 when I have 1 in either columns and no 2 in any of them.

```
data1$case=ifelse(data1$ME==2 | data1$PDR==2 ,2,ifelse(data1$ME==NA & data1$PDR==NA,NA,1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pmax`

```
data1$case <- do.call(pmax, c(data1, na.rm = TRUE))
data1$case
#[1]  2  1  1  2 NA
```

---

Regarding the OP's case with `NA`, the `==` returns `NA` for any element that is an `NA`.  So, we need to take care of the `NA` with adding a condition (`& !is.na(ME)` - for both columns)

```
with(data1, ifelse((ME == 2 & !is.na(ME)) | (PDR == 2 & !is.na(PDR)), 
         2, ifelse(is.na(ME) &is.na(PDR), NA, 1)))
#[1]  2  1  1  2 NA
```

NOTE:  The `==` for checking `NA` is not recommended as there are functions to get a logical vector when there are missing values (`is.na`, `complete.cases`)

#### data

```
data1 <- structure(list(ME = c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA), PDR = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
  2L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```